# How to implement a slide page inside a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a function like Google Image Search, which is that when you click a picture, a subpage appears in the screen below the picture. And it takes a whole line. The screenshot is showing below.
http://www.wy19900814fun.com/thumbnails/test.png

Here's my code. Is there anyone helping me to implement or at least give me some advise? I'm trying to do a function like when you click a picture, the second div class shows below the picture you click. It needs to take a whole line.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  .container {
   text-align: center;
  }
  
  .container img {
   display:inline-block;
  }
  .subpage {
   display:none;
  }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/20964301401_5d9fdf5c0d_o_large_958fe482-f2e7-4120-b4fe-016fcf612bf5_large.jpeg?v=1440873580">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/20770321799_5c81882577_o_large_c4c19c91-0532-422f-99d0-297b2731c4e3_large.jpeg?v=1440873580">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/17108089939_8d4cefd10a_o_large_3dc1d49b-cb59-432a-a8d7-b118cfd61314_large.jpeg?v=1440873578">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/17950190230_114070818c_o_large_60ce5c71-7575-49ab-be75-ed2cfed6768d_large.jpeg?v=1440873577">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15175737319_c0db73446f_o_zps867eecb9_large_858814b0-6a80-4a34-b55d-97acc179cc91_large.jpeg?v=1440873576">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15085342999_b8878e538e_o_zps54a2d381_large_f731cd55-f8d0-4e9a-8ba5-c254b4b8241d_large.jpeg?v=1440873575">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15085523427_bacc983407_o_zps2c262937_large.jpeg?v=1440873574">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15268975561_ed3f9f5c0b_o_zpsd4857119_large.jpeg?v=1440873573">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15339485796_bed118ac3c_o_zpsf0927ac3_large.jpeg?v=1440873572">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/IMG_9092_zpsc38bd27c_large.jpeg?v=1440873571">
 </div>
 
 <div class="subpage">
  <p>This is </br>just</br> a test.</br> Please show</br> subpage</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('img').click(function() {
  var $img = $(this),
      offset = $img.offset(),
      subPage = $('#subPage').hide().insertAfter('.container'),
      nextImage = $img.next(),
      finalImage = $img;
  
  if (!$img.is(':last-child')) {
    while (offset.top == nextImage.offset().top) {
      nextImage = nextImage.next();
    }
    
    finalImage = nextImage.prev();
  }
  
  subPage.html('').append($img.clone()).insertAfter(finalImage).slideDown();
});
```

```css
.container {
 text-align: center;
}

.container img {
 display:inline-block;
  width:32%;
  vertical-align:top;
}

#subPage {
  background:#222;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/20964301401_5d9fdf5c0d_o_large_958fe482-f2e7-4120-b4fe-016fcf612bf5_large.jpeg?v=1440873580">
 <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/20770321799_5c81882577_o_large_c4c19c91-0532-422f-99d0-297b2731c4e3_large.jpeg?v=1440873580">
 <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/17108089939_8d4cefd10a_o_large_3dc1d49b-cb59-432a-a8d7-b118cfd61314_large.jpeg?v=1440873578">
 <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/17950190230_114070818c_o_large_60ce5c71-7575-49ab-be75-ed2cfed6768d_large.jpeg?v=1440873577">
 <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15175737319_c0db73446f_o_zps867eecb9_large_858814b0-6a80-4a34-b55d-97acc179cc91_large.jpeg?v=1440873576">
 <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15085342999_b8878e538e_o_zps54a2d381_large_f731cd55-f8d0-4e9a-8ba5-c254b4b8241d_large.jpeg?v=1440873575">
 <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15085523427_bacc983407_o_zps2c262937_large.jpeg?v=1440873574">
 <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15268975561_ed3f9f5c0b_o_zpsd4857119_large.jpeg?v=1440873573">
 <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15339485796_bed118ac3c_o_zpsf0927ac3_large.jpeg?v=1440873572">
 <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/IMG_9092_zpsc38bd27c_large.jpeg?v=1440873571">
</div>

<div id="subPage"></div>
```

Comment: You are awesome!!!! That's exactly what I wanted. I will learn your code. Thanks Mosh!

Answer (score 0):

You could do like that :

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.container img').click(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        var subpage = $('.subpage');
        subpage.hide().empty().fadeIn(250);
        $('<img>', {'src' : src}).hide(250).appendTo(subpage).fadeIn(250);
    });
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zlen/ujquv8qd/)

Comment: Sorry for the late response but this isn't like the function in the picture. Please see the below answer.